# Display date when updating a form with type=date

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to display the current date that is saved in my database when I'm updating the registered data. When I click to update the register, all the fields with `input type=text` are shown with the data in the database, but the fields with `input type=date` show as mm/dd/yyyy, instead of the data stored. Is it possible to show the date stored with the `input type=date` in my update form? Thanks for helping.
Here is my input:

```
        <label for="birth_date">Birth Date: </label>
        <input
          type="date"
          class="form-control"
          name="birth_date"
          id="birth_date"
          value="<%= patient.birth_date %>"
        />
```

Comment: How is `patient.birth_date` formatted? It needs to be `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Modern browsers may *display* `<input type="date">` fields in mm/dd/yyyy format ([based on your locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)) but they *store* the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the value of `patient.birth_date` is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. The MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) says:

> **Note**: The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.